# Trying to post Scores and Achievements

Tags: php, facebook

I have a problem trying to post Scores and Achievements. I am using an exact copy of the example

http://developers.facebook.com/blog/post/539/

but am get the following errors.

```
CookieRegister Achievement:
true

Publish a User Achievement
{"error":{"message":"Unsupported post request.","type":"GraphMethodException"}}

Publish a User Score
{"error":{"message":"Unsupported post request.","type":"GraphMethodException"}}
```

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: can you please check you app category? you will need to categorize it as 'Games'? Also please make sure you have correct permission.

Answer (score 0):

It's possible you don't have your app configured correctly.

> These stories can only be published by apps categorized as ‘Games’ and
>   are only shown to users when playing a game. We intend to broaden the
>   types of apps that can use these new APIs in the near future.

And did you register your achievements with facebook that your app will award?

```
https://graph.facebook.com/YOUR_APP_ID/achievements?
  achievement=YOUR_ACHIEVEMENT_URL&
  display_order=YOUR_ACHIEVEMENT_DISPLAY_ORDER&
  access_token=APP_ACCESS_TOKEN
```

Notice the above has YOUR_APP_ID, not a USER_ID.  This is to register the achievement.